# How to call an unmanaged C++ DLL With CString Reference

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, command-line-interface

Using VS2010 I am building a C++/CLI wrapper DLL around an unmanaged C++ DLL that uses MFC CStrings in its public interface. The unmanaged C++ DLL contains a class that I need to access. My problem is that this class contains methods using CString references, such as:

```
BOOL GetUnits(eSysOfUnits sysUnit, CString &Unit, Cstring &Format);
```

In my C++/CLI wrapper im trying to access it like this

```
BOOL GetUmUnits(eSysU sysunit, String^ %cunit, String^ %format)
{
   GetUnits(sysunit, marshal_as<CString>(cunit), marshal_as<CString>(format));
}
```

This give me a compiler error stating

> C2665: msclr::interop::marshal_as : none of the 3 overload could convert all the argument types

The GetUmUnits will be access by a C# form. the cunit and format need to be updated by the unmananaged code.

What am I doing wrong is it not possible?

Comment: I actually did a conversion so CString cs(cuint) and safe for format then called GetUnits(sysunit, cs, cs2) this convert it back to String^ using marshal_as. it works. so i guess I answered my own question. But im wondering if its safe?

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper is going to have to convert the managed `String^` to an actual `CString` object and pass it directly. The marshaller doesn't know how to create `CString` objects.

There are different versions of `CString` in different versions of MFC, so you'll have to link against the same MFC version that the unmanaged DLL does to build one.